# Whats the HTML Tidy Config value to put every tag on a new line?

Tags: html, newline, tidy

im trying to html tidy my document

currently im' getting code like this though

```
    <div class="ImageContainer">
  <img width="740.953125" height="561" src="pages/channels_home.png" usemap="#map_channels_home" />
</div><map name="map_channels_home" id="map_channels_home">
  </map>
```

Is there a configuration value to turn this on?
I've looked here: http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html
but not sure which config value

Comment: Did you solve this in the end? Having the same problem with Html5 tidy 5.2

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend displaying it as viewed on firebug, with head body footer... close to left margin, and moving towords the right as you develop inside each div/span...
Doesn't really matter, it sould be nicely accessible if you need to change/modify your script. If you look at google's script every thing is on one line (browser speed maybe). Firebug is a browser plugin if you're wondering.

Comment: hey mate, cheers but I forgot to mention that all I want is to configure HTML Tidy so that <map name> is placed on a New Line, rather than directly after </div>

Comment: Not sure I understand.. open it with your favorite script editor put your crusor `</div> here <map>` and hit return. You can do it with windows text editor if you want. Not sure about HTML tidy

Comment: OH I GET IT NOW
you think i meant I want to Tidy my Html
No i meant i'm running "HTML tidy" script on my code
and the code being returned is as above, everything is fine except I want New tags to be on new lines
Thats why i'm looking in the HTML tidy configuration documentation to try figure out what value controls that

see here for more info what HTML Tidy is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Tidy

Comment: Check it sorry can't help, you can do it with any text editor though